# In an Android game, can you enable the player to unlock something in ANOTHER game (or see another game's high score)?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Applications of these two ideas could include enabling the player to see his or her progress in earlier games within the latest sequel, being able to keep the same character/progress across games, etc. etc.

While the best solution is likely having the player create an account they use across games, I'd like to avoid that if I can (both because players are already logging into Google Play Games, and because I currently do not have access to server infrastructure to handle doing that). Is there any other official/popular mechanism for passing data between games, or is the account route the best bet?

Comment: in simple answer "no", until and unless the other game had given you the access to its data or through content-providers. For in detail learn [Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you are looking for, [Interacting with Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) especially the Sharing Simple Data and Sharing File section. You may also refer to this documentation for [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) which suggests that you will need an `ACTION_SEND` intent filter.

> **Update Your Manifest**
>
> Intent filters inform the system what intents an application component is willing to accept. Similar to how you constructed an intent with action `ACTION_SEND` in the Sending Simple Data to Other Apps lesson, you create intent filters in order to be able to receive intents with this action. You define an intent filter in your manifest, using the `<intent-filter>` element.
>
> **Handle the Incoming Content**
>
> To handle the content delivered by an Intent, start by calling getIntent() to get Intent object. Once you have the object, you can examine its contents to determine what to do next. Keep in mind that if this activity can be started from other parts of the system, such as the launcher, then you will need to take this into consideration when examining the intent.

I think this would be a good place to start on how to pass data from one app to another. You will also need to make changes in your current implementation both in your existingt and new app for this to be possible.

Comment: I had a feeling one would need to go this route, many thanks. From the searching I've done myself it sounds like this is the best solution, even though ideally I was hoping that one does not necessarily need both apps installed at the same time (IE, unlocking something in an app not yet downloaded, or getting the high score from an uninstalled prequel). From what I've gathered that's not very doable without accounts, so I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution to this is to have all the games share a common Play Game Console configuration.  You can have multiple packageIds point to the same appId, so they see the same list of achievements, leaderboards, etc.

Depending on your specific requirements, you could simply change the descriptions of the items to describe which game they are for, or implement custom UIs to display the lists.